# Does Solr / Sunspot include new record in search query even if it's not indexed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Because of the slow indexing and resource intensive, I only set Solr to re-index in 12 hours period. So when new record is added before it's indexed, it cannot be searched, am I right?

If yes, should I change to other search system?

Comment: "Should" you? Not sure how we could answer that. I thought records were indexed when they were added--are you sure they're not?

Comment: @DaveNewton They're normally indexes on update/create, but you can tune that. Victor: Yes, if it's not in the index, it cannot be found using the index.

Comment: Thanks guys for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

Documents are only available for search after a commit. They are parsed and converted to internal formats as soon as they are submitted to Solr. That is indexing.

Your question doesn't quite make sense for a pure Solr system. Do you have an RDBMS and are you reindexing that? If so, then you are right, Solr is only updated when the records are fetched from the database, indexed, and committed.

For a shorter delay, there are a couple of options. If you have a timestamp for each record, you can periodically only reindex the changed records. They will replace the old version of the records. If you do this, you need to handle deleted records specially, usually by adding a  "deleted" column and issuing a Solr delete command for those records.

The Data Input Handler has support for delta queries, though it is a bit complicated. You also could write a bit of code to read the database and submit regular Solr updates in the dedicated Solr XML format.

Updating frequently might hurt search performance. Solr gets a lot of performance from caching results. Those caches are cleared after a commit. Check the statistics page for the cache hit ratio in your query result cache. If that is high, frequent updates could cause performance problems.